# how to make div html tag that working like input type radio button?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make a div button that acts like a radio button.

It currently works likes a checkbox. How do I make it work like an input(type radio) tag?

This is the code that works likes checkbox

```css
    .gender {
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 32px;
        margin: 4px;
        padding-left: 32px;
        background: left no-repeat url('https://icons-for-free.com/iconfiles/png/512/radio+button+unchecked+24px-131987943262195581.png');
        background-size: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .gender.checked {
        background-image: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-vol-3-1/16/radio-button-on-checked--round-circle-512.png");
    }
```

```html
<div style="text-align: left">
    <div class="gender checked" onclick="this.classList.toggle('checked')">
        Unspecified
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="gender" onclick="this.classList.toggle('checked')">
        Male
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="gender" onclick="this.classList.toggle('checked')">
        Female
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make it act like a radio button

Comment: Your unchecked image is giving a 403 - do you have a link to an unchecked image that can be included here?  Would make the snippet more complete.

Comment: Check the pen
https://codepen.io/thebrown/pen/oNNvPvp

Comment: 403 on the pen as well and checking the pen invites close votes as all the code should be in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fine with changing a little of your html then you can try this.

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="unspecified" />
<label for="unspecified" class="gender">
    Unspecified
</label>
```

Then we can set the "false" radio to be checked like this:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked+.gender {
  background-image: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-vol-3-1/16/radio-button-on-checked--round-circle-512.png");
}
```

**Demo**

```css
.gender {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin: 4px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  background: left no-repeat url('https://icons-for-free.com/iconfiles/png/512/radio+button+unchecked+24px-131987943262195581.png');
  background-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gender.checked {
  background-image: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-vol-3-1/16/radio-button-on-checked--round-circle-512.png");
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+.gender {
  background-image: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/interface-vol-3-1/16/radio-button-on-checked--round-circle-512.png");
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: left">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="unspecified" />
  <label for="unspecified" class="gender">
      Unspecified
  </label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="Male" />
  <label for="Male" class="gender">
      Male
  </label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="Female" />
  <label for="Female" class="gender">
      Female
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: upvoted for just using a radio (albeit hidden) and letting the browser handle it for you